# SQL Client with inner join exploration

Tags: database, squirrel-sql

I have a database which I sometime like to manually explore, in order to get info.

I currently use squirrel sql client, which is quite good, but there's a feature I miss badly : when I issue a simple select to a table, let's say there's a line I want to know references.

For that purpose, I need to manually write big sql request with inner joins, which can be quite daunting...

So my question : is there any (possibly free) SQL Client that just lets you explore the possible inner joins?

For example, a click on the line id would give me all the lines from other tables referencing it, just as simply as an hypertext link would do...

Comment: Update : I upgraded my version of Squirrel SQL, they now have a SQL generator which does inner joins automagically :) That's definitely cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [DBeauty](http://dbeauty.sourceforge.net/):
"A relationship-oriented Database Browser.
Provides insight into both the data and the interrelation of the rows."

Comment: That's a rather cool way to explore data indeed. Much faster than manually writing all these inner joins :)